# sending a http url request

Tags: java, android, http

i have been trying to copy the HttpURLConnection snippet from Android developer page into my project just to see if i can make an internet connection and every time i run the function my app closes. i am not sure why the application is failing and any help would be appreciated. this code is being placed inside `public class main extends Activity`

main.java:

```
public void showHelp() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try{
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            //readStream(in);
        } finally{
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

i commented out readStream because i thought the conversion might have been the problem but thats not the case. the function is:

```
private String readStream(InputStream is) {
        try {
          ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          int i = is.read();
          while(i != -1) {
            bo.write(i);
            i = is.read();
          }
          return bo.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          return "";
        }
    }
```

if posting log cat result helps please let me know. also i am fairly new at android programming and the first function is being called when a menu option is clicked but i didn't think that was relevant. also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

are included in the android manifest xml

logcat error:

```
02-04 21:27:14.468: W/dalvikvm(16978): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4208d2a0)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.MeadowEast.audiotest.MainActivity.showHelp(MainActivity.java:369)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.MeadowEast.audiotest.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:97)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2625)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1061)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:179)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3083)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3983)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
02-04 21:27:14.492: E/AndroidRuntime(16978):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

new AsyncTask code:

```
private abstract class myTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        protected void doInBackground(String addressName) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL(addressName);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try{
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                //readStream(in);
            } finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate() {
             //do nothing
         }

         protected void onPostExecute() {
             //toast me
         }
    }
```

being called from:

```
 public void showHelp(){
        new myTask().execute("http://www.android.com/");
    }
```

i can't load to android device i get the problem: Cannot instantiate the Type main.mytask

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Post your logcat. With what version of Android are you testing?

Comment: done and Android 4.1.2 with target API19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look your logcat, your problem is NetworkOnMainThreadException so that put your urlconnection into others thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showHelp();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: your code didn't crash on and seems to be working(i need to keep testing it) but i don't understand it can you please tell me a little bit more about what its doing.

Comment: In android, you can't do network action in mainThread because that will cause your UI lag, so that if you want to do network action you need to do it in others thread. the code I post is one way, and the other way is use AsyncTask

Comment: You can also check this tutorial.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: yes i have been looking into AsyncTask and posted some code above that didn't work for me. Your solution work but upon completion does the thread close automatically or do i need to close it. what if the server lags is their a timeout in which the thread will close on its own?

Comment: You don't close it, it will be closed in the work end, AsyncTask can do UI change in onPostExecute. This way what I post if you want to do UI change you need to use handler http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/

Comment: Because Android don't allow network action in main thread so that if you forget create thread to do network action that will cause NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can think of is that you are placing network communication on the main thread. You are not allowed to do so. You can use AsyncTask

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
```

For testing you can add the following in your Main Activity but it is consider bad practice.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: ok i'll give it a try and come back. i tried creating an AsyncTask before but i couldn't get it running so i tried on main thread instead without saving the code. also should this new class be made in a different file and how would i call it from main?

Comment: Actually it is recommended to use AsyncTask as an inner class. So you can add it to your current class.

Comment: i made some changes but i did something wrong now i can't run the code. posted the error at the bottom of main question

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to do network operation in different thread